# Rails 3: Why a select box does not pass the right value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have the following select box that was created using nested form:

```
<select name="product[shop_attributes][id]" id="product_shop_attributes_id">
  <option value="23">KMART</option>
  <option value="24">Super Shop</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="22">TARGET</option>
  <option value="new">Create New Shop</option>
</select>
```

`selected="selected"` was created by passing `:selected => "22"` to `f.select` options.

The problem is that no matter what option is selected, the submitted value is always `"22"`.

I noticed that a hidden input is created, which I believe causes the problem:

```
<input type="hidden" value="22" name="product[shop_attributes][id]" id="product_shop_attributes_id">
```

Thus, there are 2 elements with `id=product_shop_attributes_id`.

What could cause to this hidden input field to be generated ?

---

Relevant code of select box creation:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :shop do |sf| %>
    sf.select(:id, <options>, {:prompt => true, :selected => <default_value>})
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Relevant controller code:

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id]) # the select box indeed gets it's initial value from @product
end

def update
  @temp = params.inspect
end
```

`update.html.erb:`

```
<%= @temp %>
```

I see here always the same (no matter what option is selected):

```
"product"=>{"shop_attributes"=>{"id"=>"22"},...}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass :selected — you're using a model form. You only need that with select_tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as I mentioned in the question, the hidden input field with the same `id` as the `select`.

I opened a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488518/rails-3-why-an-empty-nested-form-generates-a-hidden-input-field) to investigate why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the rails generated HTML. It's probably the way you're accessing it in your controller. Could you post the original rails code that generated this HTML and the code you are using to process it?

Comment: I added the relevant info to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Please see my update. I noticed that a hidden field with same id is generated. What could cause this ?

Comment: Please paste the rest of your ERB.