# Rails 3: Why an empty nested form generates a hidden input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, hidden-field

Why this:

```
# edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :shop do |sf| %>
    # Nothing here
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

generates a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" value="23" name="product[shop_attributes][id]" id="product_shop_attributes_id">
```

?

Relevant controller code:

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'll be because the @product you're editing has a shop. Rails has inserted that in the fields_for so that when the form is submitted, it knows which shop those nested attributes are for. It's default nested attributes behaviour.

Comment: I am having a problem related to this. I have an edit form, that when submited is inserting a new instance in the db instead of editing the one in the hidden field. I don't know in which direction to look for an answer...